# cycle through entries in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, keyboard

Im writing a game that has two sets of buttons. The first set is like blank spaces, and the second set is a custom keyboard.

So I've created a dictionary to keep track of selected buttons (blank spaces) in my interface. The user can select say 5 of these and update all of their titles at once. When the user presses a key (on my custom keyboard made of buttons in a separate subview) I want to change all of the titles to show the letter on the key the pressed.

I have my keys numbered (alphanumerically) from 1 to 26 (ie. a=1, z=26) and the current set of labels on the blanks will be kept in similar numeric form in an array called "currentSolution"

Im imagining i can set up a for loop to go through selected blanks and give them all the title of whatever key is selected in the keyPressed method. Can anyone give me any guidance here? im kinda a noob and dont really know how i should go about this

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  (only in ios 4)-

```
   [yourDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"dic = %@ : %@", key,object);

  //Do what you want for every object...
    UILabel *label =  (UILabel*)object;
    label.text = @"bla bla";

    }
}];
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I ended up giving each button a tag and entering them into an array so i could call them later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW - You don't need the array, you can call them with [UIView viewWithTag:]